# Does this code rotate a cloud of points about the cross product counterclockwise or clockwise?

Tags: c++

I found this very interesting blog post, but the author does not specify when this rotates a cloud of points counterclockwise or clockwise around a vector pointing towards you); can someone tell me which it is? Thanks. This is important to me because I'm writing a simulation that relies on this point! Here is the blog post:http://www.programming-techniques.com/2012/03/3d-rotation-algorithm-about-arbitrary.html

Comment: You can leave the author a comment or send an email

Comment: Why don't you try with a small example and se what happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation of the rotation matrix used in the blog is [here](http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/). The Rz matrix used in the derivation is a counter clockwise rotation about the z axis, so the rotation is counter clockwise about the (u, v, w) vector.