# Rotating a vector by angle and axis in java

Tags: java, matrix, vector

I know there are lots of questions and answers about this topic or related but i've beenn trying for 2 hours and still haven't benn able to figure it.

I would like to get a function that looks like this:

```
public static Vector rotateVector(Vector v, Vector axis, double angle){

}
```

Where the axis is a unit vector that defines the plane of rotation (the vector v rotates towards the vector axis if angle is positive)

I have already taken a look at rotation matrices but haven't been able to implement those to the above function

Comment: I found some classes that might work. A Matrix class http://pastebin.com/6WpiAX5R and a Vector class http://pastebin.com/hsmTVhT8. The Matrix class has a constructor that takes an axis and an angle and the Vector class has a rotate method that takes a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotating (x, y, z) counter clockwise around **unit** vector (u, v, w) by angle theta produces a vector (xPrime, yPrime, zPrime):

```
double xPrime = u*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1d - Math.cos(theta)) 
                + x*Math.cos(theta)
                + (-w*y + v*z)*Math.sin(theta);
double yPrime = v*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1d - Math.cos(theta))
                + y*Math.cos(theta)
                + (w*x - u*z)*Math.sin(theta);
double zPrime = w*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1d - Math.cos(theta))
                + z*Math.cos(theta)
                + (-v*x + u*y)*Math.sin(theta);
```

Source [here](http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/).

Answer (score 3):

Got it, thanks @Chris K. Here is the java function:

```
public static Vector rotateVectorCC(Vector vec, Vector axis, double theta){
    double x, y, z;
    double u, v, w;
    x=vec.getX();y=vec.getY();z=vec.getZ();
    u=axis.getX();v=axis.getY();w=axis.getZ();
    double xPrime = u*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1d - Math.cos(theta)) 
            + x*Math.cos(theta)
            + (-w*y + v*z)*Math.sin(theta);
    double yPrime = v*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1d - Math.cos(theta))
            + y*Math.cos(theta)
            + (w*x - u*z)*Math.sin(theta);
    double zPrime = w*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1d - Math.cos(theta))
            + z*Math.cos(theta)
            + (-v*x + u*y)*Math.sin(theta);
    return new Vector(xPrime, yPrime, zPrime);
}
```

However, I will keep the check on Chris' answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to rotate a vector.

```
private Vector rotateZ(Vector vector,double angle) { // angle in radians

  //normalize(vector); // No  need to normalize, vector is already ok...

  float x1 = (float)(vector.x * Math.cos(angle) - vector.y * Math.sin(angle));

  float y1 = (float)(vector.x * Math.sin(angle) + vector.y * Math.cos(angle)) ;

  return new Vector(x1, y1);

}
```

Comment: This is correct if the vector being rotated is already in the the plane perpendicular to the rotation axis. If it's not, project the vector onto the plane and apply the the rotation. The out of plane component is unaffected.

Comment: Yes, i think it works but only for the **Z axis**!! What about doing it on any given axis?

Comment: @BIELSIMON Do you know how to apply matrices to vectors

Comment: @MCMastery I think it is just multipliying but what i want is rotating at **any** axis, given as a parameter. Then it is not just multiplying by the specific rotation matrix. How should it be done then?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195700/does-this-code-rotate-a-cloud-of-points-about-the-cross-product-counterclockwise/31195885#31195885) is in c++ but it should be easy to extend to java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rotation for x,y and z axis then you should use rotation matrices all at once.

NewVector = [Rotation_X]*[Rotation_Y]*[Rotation_Z]*OldVector

Here Rotation_X,Rotation_Y and Rotation_Z are 3x3 matrices. (You can see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html)

The order of multiplication depends on the problem but i guess you want only one-axis rotation (i.e. the other 2 matrices become identity matrices)

So just putting an if-block you can set the correct matrix, and leave the rest as identity matrices.

Hope this helps.